# Align vertically an image and two lines of text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I read many articles, many posts here, but unfortunately I can't center 2 lines of text and an image vertically.

```
<a class="button" href="">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x30/cf97cf/fff">
    Button
    <span>Button alt</span>
</a>
```

I would like the 2 lines next to the image (centered), and center the whole content vertically in the `.button`.

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

span {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

At CSS-Tricks I found an article, but I don't want to use `position:absolute` to center. Is there any clean way to center the texts/image in the `<a>`?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fx3eozd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also wrap the `text` and `span` inside a `div` then wrap that `div` and `img` inside another `div` then add these classes:

also add `display: inline-block;` on your `img`

```
    .center {   
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%); 
    }
   .btnText {
      vertical-align: middle; 
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

### **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5ay25ryg/3/)**

---

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
span {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ccc;;
  display: block; 
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {  
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
   .btnText {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="">
  <div class="center">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x30/cf97cf/fff">
      <div class="btnText">
        Button  
        <span>Button alt</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I would like the 'Button alt' in same line, and centered to image.

Comment: No, I mean under the 'Button' text, in same line and centered vertically to the image.

Comment: yes, but when I change the size of the image it's not: https://jsfiddle.net/5ay25ryg/2/

Comment: change the css of your `.center`  class  `.center {   
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}` https://jsfiddle.net/Lpv5h4n6/

Answer (score 2):

You can add `display: table-cell` to element with class `.button` and `vertical-align: middle`:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.button {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  display: table-cell;/*change display to table-cell*/
  vertical-align: middle;/*add vertical align middle*/
}
span {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x30/cf97cf/fff">Button
  <span>Button alt</span>
</a>
```

Comment: "button alt" should be under "Button", could you modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `img` and `span` inside a `div` (with class center)

```
<a class="button" href="">
    <div class="center">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x30/cf97cf/fff">
        Button
        <span>Button alt</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

then add this css:

```
.center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Explain: Set position of `div` with top `50%`, then move it to top with 50% its height (translateY by -50%)